# TypeError when comparing multiple columns in merged tables

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to answer this question for class:  **What is the total number of orders containing items sold at less than the MSRP?**

I merged the Order Details table with the Products table. I was able to determine the items sold by subtracting Quantity sold from Quantity in Stock. I am having trouble with the comparison between Buy Price and MSRP.

````
# This requires merging of the products table and orderDetails table
# create a total of orders value for items sold
# quantityInStock - quantityOrdered = items sold
# create value for items sold only under the MSRP value (buyPrice < MSRP)
# selecting only items sold at less than MSRP, summing results

Q1_df = pd.merge(orderDetails_df, products_df, on= 'productCode')
print(Q1_df)
items_sold = Q1_df['quantityInStock'] - Q1_df['quantityOrdered']
print(items_sold)
# items sold = 2996
Q1_df['buyPrice'] = Q1_df['buyPrice'].astype(int)
Q1_df['MSRP'] = Q1_df['MSRP'].astype(int)

print(Q1_df)

# Q1_df.query('buyPrice < MSRP')
yeet = Q1_df[Q1_df['buyPrice']<'MSRP'][[items_sold]].sum()
print(yeet)```

This is the error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/nicsw/Documents/MERRIMACK COLLEGE MSBA/Fall 2 2020/Foundations of Data Management/Module 6/Module_6_setup.py", line 115, in <module>
    yeet = Q1_df[Q1_df['buyPrice']<'MSRP'][[items_sold]].sum()
  File "C:\Users\nicsw\anaconda3\envs\Module 6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 65, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "C:\Users\nicsw\anaconda3\envs\Module 6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 370, in wrapper
    res_values = comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
  File "C:\Users\nicsw\anaconda3\envs\Module 6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 241, in comparison_op
    return invalid_comparison(lvalues, rvalues, op)
  File "C:\Users\nicsw\anaconda3\envs\Module 6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\invalid.py", line 34, in invalid_comparison
    raise TypeError(f"Invalid comparison between dtype={left.dtype} and {typ}")
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=int32 and str
````

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct because your comparing an int with a str here:

`yeet = Q1_df[Q1_df['buyPrice'] < 'MSRP'][[items_sold]].sum()`

I think you want

`yeet = Q1_df[Q1_df['buyPrice'] < Q1_df['MSRP']][[items_sold]].sum()`

Comment: this doesn't work; coming up with another error message like so: ```raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")```

Comment: then says this: ```"None of [Index([(2694, 2682, 2703, .... , dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"```

Comment: please post a sample of `Q1_df`